# JQuery function to click button causes maximum stack size

Tags: jquery

I have created this function to click a button based on its ID.

```
function clickBtn(button_id) {
    console.log(button_id);
    $(button_id).click();
}
```

I added in the console.log and when i check it, it adds the same ID (from the arguement) over 805 times to the console then returns the maximum stack size exceeded error.

I am calling the function like this:

```
<div class="col-md-6 price-boxes" onclick="clickBtn('#btn_book_20');">
                <?php echo $twenty_hours; ?>

                <div style="position:absolute; bottom:10px; width:100%;">
                <input type="hidden" name="price_20" value="<?php echo $twenty_hours_price; ?>" readonly="readonly" />
                <button type="submit" name="book" id="btn_book_20" value="20">Book Now</button>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.col -->
```

if the button itself is clicked, it works fine and doesnt exceed the stack size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function that you are calling is being called when the outer div is being clicked. 
Inside the javascript click function you are calling another click on the button inside the div.

As the button is inside the div it the click will propagate up the DOM and also trigger the onClick function of the outer div; calling the same function again. 
This results in the function calling itself recursively and causing the stack to run out of memory.

Why not try wrapping the input fields in a form and using the following line to submit the form:

```
function clickBtn(button_id) {
   $("#form").submit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your question is "Why does this happen?"

Triggering a click even on the button bubbles up to your div and triggers your onclick handler which again triggers a click event on the button which bubbles up again (in an endless loop).

If your intention is to submit the form, then I'd say don't bother with triggering a click event on the button. Instead, trigger a submit event on the form `$('#form-id').submit()`